# Out of Memory when reading a string from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, performance, memory

I'm running into the strangest thing that I can't figure out. I have a SQL table with a bunch of reports stored in an ntext field. When I copied and pasted the value of one of them into notepad and saved it (used Visual Studio to grab the value from a smaller report in a differente row), the raw txt file was about 5Mb. When I try to get this same data using SqlDataReader and convert it to a string, I get an out of memory exception. Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
string output = "";
string cmdtext = "SELECT ReportData FROM Reporting_Compiled WHERE CompiledReportTimeID = @CompiledReportTimeID";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdtext, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("CompiledReportTimeID", CompiledReportTimeID));
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    output = reader.GetString(0); // <--- exception happens here
}
reader.Close();
```

I tried creating an object and a stringbuilder to grab the data, but I still get the same out of memory exception. I've also tried using reader.GetValue(0).ToString() as well to no avail. The query only returns 1 row, and when I run it in SQL Management Studio its as happy as can be.

The exception thrown is:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled by user code  
Message=Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.  
Source=mscorlib  
 StackTrace:  
 at System.String.CreateStringFromEncoding(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteLength, Encoding       encoding)  
   at System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count)  
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadString(Int32 length)  
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ReadSqlStringValue(SqlBuffer value, Byte type, Int32 length, Encoding encoding, Boolean isPlp, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)  
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)  
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumnData()  
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout)  
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)  
   at Reporting.Web.Services.InventoryService.GetPrecompiledReportingData(DateTime ReportTime, String ReportType) in   C:\Projects\Reporting\Reporting.Web\Services\InventoryService.svc.cs:line 3244  
   at SyncInvokeGetPrecompiledReportingData(Object , Object[] , Object[] )  
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)  
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)  
 InnerException:   
    null
```

I had tested with other row numbers that appeared to work, but that was a false positive as those test ID's had no data. I pulled some other test ID's after looking at the table that contain reports that are near identical, and I get the same exception. Maybe its how the string is encoded? The data stored in the table is a JSON encoded string that was generated out of a really gnarly class I made somewhere else, in case that helps.

Here is the preceding code block:

```
// get the report time ID
int CompiledReportTimeTypeID = CompiledReportTypeIDs[ReportType];
int CompiledReportTimeID = -1;
cmdtext = "SELECT CompiledReportTimeID FROM Reporting_CompiledReportTime WHERE CompiledReportTimeTypeID = @CompiledReportTimeTypeID AND CompiledReportTime = @ReportTime";
cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdtext, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("CompiledReportTimeTypeID", CompiledReportTimeTypeID));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ReportTime", ReportTime));
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    CompiledReportTimeID = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
}
reader.Close();
```

CompiledReportTypeIDs is a dictionary that gets the correct CompiledReportTimeTypeID based on a string parameter that's fed in at the beginning of the method. ReportTime is a DateTime that is fed in earlier.

Edit:
I am going to drop the table and recreate it with the ReportData field as nvarchar(MAX) instead of ntext, just to rule out a SQL data type issue. It's a long shot and I'll update again with what I find.

Edit2:
Changing the field in the table to nvarchar(max) had no effect. I also tried using output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString() as well, with no impact. I'm trying to see if there is a max size for SqlDataReader. When I copied the value of the text from SQL Mgmt Studio, it was only 43Kb when saved in notepad. To verify this, I pulled a report with a known working ID (a smaller report), and when I copied the value straight out of Visual Studio and dumped it in notepad it was around 5MB! That means these big reports are probably in the ~20MB range sitting in a nvarchar(max) field.

Edit3:
I rebooted everything, to include my dev IIS server, the SQL server, and my dev laptop. Now it seems to be working. This isn't the answer as to why this happened though. I'm leaving this question open for explanations as to what happened, and I'll mark one of those as an answer.

Edit4:
Having said that, I ran another test without changing a thing and the same exception has returned. I'm really starting to think that this is a SQL issue. I'm updating the tags on this question. I made a separate app that runs the exact same query and it runs fine.

Edit5:
I have implemented sequential access as per one of the answers below. Everything gets read into a stream properly, but when I try to write it out to a string I'm still getting the out of memory exception. Would this indicate the issue of getting a contiguous block of memory? Here is how I implemented the buffering:

```
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
            long startIndex = 0;
            long retval = 0;
            int bufferSize = 100;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Reset the starting byte for the new CLOB.
                startIndex = 0;

                // Read bytes into buffer[] and retain the number of bytes returned.
                retval = reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                // Continue while there are bytes beyond the size of the buffer.
                while (retval == bufferSize)
                {
                    writer.Write(buffer);
                    writer.Flush();

                    // Reposition start index to end of last buffer and fill buffer.
                    startIndex += bufferSize;
                    retval = reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                //output = reader.GetString(0);
            }
            reader.Close();
            stream.Position = 0L;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            output = sr.ReadToEnd(); <---- Exception happens here
            //output = new string(buffer);
```

Edit6:
To add to this, when OOM exception happens I see the IIS worker process (which holds the method that is running) hit almost 700MB. This is running on IIS Express and not the full IIS on the production server. Would this have anything to do with it? Also when I call Byte[] data = stream.ToArray() I intermittently get the OOM as well. I think what I really need is a way to give more memory to this process, but I don't know where to configure this.

Edit7:
I just changed my dev server from using IIS Express on my local machine to the built-in Visual Studio web server. The OOM exception is now gone. I really think it was the allocating a contiguous block of memory issue, and for whatever reason IIS Express wouldn't fork it over. Now that it is running fine, I will publish to my full blown server on 2008R2 running the regular IIS7 to see how it goes.

Comment: You should include the complete error message as well.

Comment: How large is the string that's being returned?  In other words, how large is ReportData?

Comment: Show the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Do you really have "new SqlParameter("CompiledReportTimeID",..." or is it really "new SqlParameter("@CompiledReportTimeID",..." ?

Comment: It doesn't have the @ in the first argument for the SqlParameter, which has worked fine for me so far. I just tested it with @ in the first argument, and I have the same result.

Comment: You could try `using` blocks around your `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` and `SqlConnection` objects.

Comment: Copying large strings out of SSMS isn't a reliable measure because SSMS sets an upper limit on how large a string it will return.  If you want to measure string length reliably in SSMS, add `Len(col)` to your query.

Comment: Is the Sql Server running from the same machine you're running the app?  If so, in order to optimize queries, depending on your table/index configurations, sql server might load so much data in memory to the point of starving the resources to run your app. Check the Process Monitor if that's happening, and if it is, set a limit in Sql Server to memory consumption.

Comment: Nope, I have it running on a separate server. I was watching the activity monitor, and nothing was maxing out.

Comment: Given the size of your data, you may need to also write the retrieved data in chunks to the output stream instead of trying to bring all of the data into memory as a string instance. Can you clarify what you intend to do with the report data after it is retrieved? Are you just writing it to the output stream of a web response?

Comment: I tried using the MSDN article to chunk the data using sequential access and getchars, but as soon as I tried to get the length by feeding in a null value I got the OOM. This big 'ol JSON string is converted back into a big ugly object that is used by a Silverlight client. The code above is from a WCF service that sends it back as a string. I really need to shrink it down, but I was planning on doing that later. Maybe that later is now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should try to read the data sequentially by specifying the [command behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx) when you execute the reader. Per the documentation, **Use SequentialAccess to retrieve large values and binary data. Otherwise, an OutOfMemoryException might occur and the connection will be closed**.

While sequential access is typically used on large binary data, based on the MSDN documentation you can use it to read large amounts of character data as well.

> When accessing the data in the BLOB field, use the GetBytes or
>   GetChars typed accessors of the DataReader, which fill an array with
>   data. You can also use GetString for character data; however. to
>   conserve system resources you might not want to load an entire BLOB
>   value into a single string variable. You can instead specify a
>   specific buffer size of data to be returned, and a starting location
>   for the first byte or character to be read from the returned data.
>   GetBytes and GetChars will return a long value, which represents the
>   number of bytes or characters returned. If you pass a null array to
>   GetBytes or GetChars, the long value returned will be the total number
>   of bytes or characters in the BLOB. You can optionally specify an
>   index in the array as a starting position for the data being read.

This [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows how to perform sequential access. I believe you can use the [GetChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getchars.aspx) method to read the textual data.

Comment: This sounds promising. I need to jet for the day, but I will try this first thing in the morning.

Comment: The buffering works great, but I'm getting the OOM exception when trying to write the stream I made to a string. When I used .GetChars() instead of .GetBytes(), I would get the OOM immediately as I was trying to get the length of the field to instantiate the char array that would contain the results.

Comment: You could use DATALENGTH to return the total length as part of the result set, and then use that value to construct the array prior to reading the result in chunks.

Comment: I will try this! I'm out of the office until next week, but I will try this first thing Monday morning.

Comment: I think you may also need to read the stream in buffers instead of using ReadToEnd(). Good luck.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it is the closest to what was going on. Turns out that IIS Express is the culprit, but chunking the return string is the proper way to go.

Comment: @Oppositional your answer helped me a lot! Thank you! Maybe my clarifications will be helpful for someone. In my code I replaced the following lines `SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); columnValue = reader[columnIndex];` with `SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess); columnValue = reader.GetString(columnIndex);` and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Fundamentally, a `System.OutOfMemoryException` doesn't just occur when you are out of memory, but when you cannot allocate a single contiguous block of memory for an object.  You'll often see that error when trying to create a very large array, or load a large bitmap object, or sometimes when creating large XmlDocuments...

`Array` and `String` typically need to be allocated contiguously, ie can't be broken up into pieces and allocated into empty spaces in memory.

This likely isn't a SQL issue and is more an issue with the SqlReader trying to allocate a string large enough to contain the data in a row.

You mentioned that it worked properly after a reboot, so let's assume your code is fundamentally correct (possibly can still be optimised to rather expose the data as a stream instead of buffering the recordset) and that the current symptom is environmental. A freshly rebooted machine possibly doesn't have as much fragmented memory, but as you used it more, the memory fragmented and the error returned...

You *may* be able to prove the contiguous memory theory by closing as many other programs as possible, and adding code to force a `GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration)` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y46kxc5e.aspx)) before the code with the error.  This isn't a guarantee, as the memory allocated to your process may still be fragmented.

I think streaming the value might be the way to stop the error occurring, and better to avoid trying to buffer everything into a string.  The downside to this is that you will keep the database connection open while the result is streamed / consumed by the rest of the program and that will bring its own overheads.  I'm not sure what your code needs to do with the result, but if it needs to work with a `String` instance, you may need to expand the memory available to the process (several ways to help that, but may be off-topic - leave a comment and I can add to this answer if needed)

Comment: I tried forcing the GC to no avail (good idea though!). I implemented buffering as per Oppositional's answer, and I'm getting the OOM when I try to dump the stream to a string. That leads me to agree with the memory allocation issue. Do you have a link to a guide I can follow to expand available process memory? I should find a way to do what I need without this of course, but something like that will work for now.

Comment: I'd really recommend against trying to tweak the environment settings to get the memory to work.  Do you have the option of streaming the data to the destination? e.g. imagine you are the pumping station between two dams, you can't suck up all the water in one dam before pumping it into the other one. You have to flush one buffer at a time.  I think the problem is trying to dump all the data into a string - best to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 0):

wild guess here.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("CompiledReportTimeID", CompiledReportTimeID));
```

you missed the @ sign. so it replaces both instances of CompiledReportTimeID with the id and you get all the results instead because of the equality?

Comment: If I add the @ into the first arg for the SQL parameter, I still get the same result. Stack Overflow formatted the CompiledReportTimeID funny, but it is just an int. I named the parameter the same thing as the int, which also happens to be the same name as the field in table. Probably not a best practice to name it that way (I'll fix it later once I get this silly thing working)