# Retrieve large file from database CLOB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle, clob

I am working with asp.net and an Oracle SQL database.

I have a simple procedure in the database which returns a file (in this case an XML file) based on a given ID. In the .net application I open up an OracleConnection and read the file to a string with the OracleDataReader.

This works fine until the file size becomes very large (360mb),  which causes an 'System.OutOfMemoryException' fault,  which I am guessing happens because the process goes over 800mb of memory usage.

Is there a better way of retrieving the file or is it possible to increase the 800mb limit? Time is not an issue here.

Procedure in database

```
PROCEDURE get_xml(xml_id    IN NUMBER,
                  p_records OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
  BEGIN

    OPEN p_records FOR
      SELECT xml
        FROM allxml
      WHERE id = xml_id;

  END get_xml;
```

c# code

```
using (OracleConnection oConn = new OracleConnection(ora_connection))
{
    Procedure proc = null;
    OracleParameter result = null;
    oConn.Open();
    OracleDataReader dr = null;
    proc = Procedure.CreateProcedure("get_xml", oConn)
        .Number("xml_id", id)
        .RefCursor("p_records", out result)
                        .ExecuteReader(out dr);
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        xml = dr.GetString(0);
    }
}

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

return doc;
```

As you can see I load the file into string and then create an xml so I can process it .

Comment: Why do you read the file to a string? What do you expect to do with it?

Comment: post some code of reading the clob from oracle , then only we can suggest something.

Comment: There's not room to hold all the xml in memory at one time. You may be forced to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15146498/814064

Comment: Did you explored compressing the data while sending?

Answer (score 0):

A best approach for multi-db app can be to persist on DB only a path/link to the file and store that large blob in file system.